# Spark Apache source code

Tags: java, python, matrix, apache-spark

I work now a lot with Spark. For example, I produce the different evaluations with MLlib package and recommender systems (Java or Python). I already have seen the documentation about [Spark on github](https://github.com/apache/spark). According the documentation I can train my model in Spark with the calling of `train` method. Here is:

[JavaRecommendationExample](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/JavaRecommendationExample.java)

I'm specially interested in the code lines 50-53:

```
// Build the recommendation model using ALS
int rank = 10;
int numIterations = 10;
MatrixFactorizationModel model = ALS.train(JavaRDD.toRDD(ratings), rank, numIterations, 0.01);
```

I would like to know the source code for this method.

Something else, I already found someself possible implementation in [Python example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.py). I'm particularly interested for the lines 240-275. Here is the documentation in the code:

> Train a matrix factorization model given an RDD of ratings by users
>       for a subset of products. The ratings matrix is approximated as the
>       product of two lower-rank matrices of a given rank (number of
>       features). To solve for these features, ALS is run iteratively with
>       a configurable level of parallelism.

In the code below I don't see any iterations over matrices. Can somebody help me and provide to the right source code, where iteration steps are implemented? Or please confirm here that the train method is not an open source.

Comment: What you are asking is not clear ! What does that mean `Can somebody help me and provide to the right source code, where iteration steps are implemented? Or please confirm here that the train method is not an open source.` ?

Comment: @eliasah, my question is, how the method train is implemented.

Comment: Tried google? Tried eclipse (like: I assume that within your eclipse project, you are pointing to one or multiple JARs for the SPARK stuff. Very often, those JARs come with source code; or at least; there are separate source code JARs available ... make them available to eclipse, and "F3" takes you to the source you are looking for). Worst case ... turn to some java decompiler, like jd-gui.

Comment: @Jagermeister, ok, I have JARs for the SPARK stuff in Eclipse, going to try it. Thank you

Comment: [Here you go](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L598) ! Nevertheless I'm voting to close this question as it is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know how deep you've searched in the `train` method but there's something like:

```
for (iter <- 1 to maxIter) {
    ...
}
```

(l.651 for implicits and l.672 for explicit with the source code of Spark 1.6.0). You can find the source code on spark's page and look at `org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS` (note that the implementation is now on ML and not on MLLib).

[Here's the source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L598) (from the comments above!)

Comment: ok, I look before only MLlib. Thank you a lot. It seems to be right direction for me.

Comment: yup, it's been move in 1.4 or 1.5 if I remember well! You can see it through the line NewALS.train[Int](...) in MLlib's version.